# Variable is not declared or inaccessible due to its protection level.

Tags: vb.net, variables, declaration

Im new in visual basic and right now I'm studying how to import csv file to database. I have this codes that imports csv file to access database but I keep getting this error:

```
'txtFile' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level
```

Here is the code.

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.Windows
Imports System.Collections

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim cnAccess As New OleDbConnection("provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;data source=" & Application.StartupPath & "C:\Users\vissia18\Desktop\ReportDB2.accdb;")

        Dim op1 As New OpenFileDialog
        op1.ShowDialog()
        txtFile.Text = op1.FileName

        Dim QryInsert As String = "", QryCreate As String = ""
        Dim i As Integer
        Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand
        Dim Fnm As String = txtFile.Text
        Dim s1 As String
        Dim s2(5) As String
        Dim freader As New IO.StreamReader(Fnm, False)
        cmd.Connection = cnAccess
        cnAccess.Open()
        While (freader.EndOfStream = False)
            s1 = freader.ReadLine
            s2 = s1.Split(",")
            QryInsert = "Insert Into Report Values (" & s2(0) & ",'" & s2(1) & "'," & s2(2) & ")"
            cmd.CommandText = QryInsert
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End While
        MsgBox("Data Imported Successfully")
        cnAccess.Close()

    End Sub

End Class
```

Please correct me if I'm wrong somewhere else. Any help will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`txtFile` is not declared in your above code. You need to declare variables before using them.

Try to replace

```
txtFile.Text = op1.FileName
[....]
Dim Fnm As String = txtFile.Text
```

with

```
Dim txtFile as String = op1.FileName
[....]
Dim Fnm As String = txtFile
```

Comment: but I have an exception which is on this code: Dim freader As New IO.StreamReader(Fnm, False). It said that the process is being used by another process. do you know what happened?

Comment: Answer edited due to a mistake. You need to declare Fnm as well .Sorry. Also make sure you don't have the file open in Notepad or any other editor.